# The updateDocument api in the Discovery module of ibm's watson-developer-cloud Node.js sdk insists on a file parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson-discovery

I am trying to insert/update documents in IBM's Discovery service via the watson-developer-cloud Node.js SDK, and it's not working.  Some of my documents don't have an associated file, so they are metadata-only.  [This documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#update-doc) says that `You must provide document content, metadata, or both.` However, the *updateDocument* call fails if you try to update a metadata-only document.

I tracked down the problem to line 607 in **node-sdk/discovery/v1.js** which is `requiredParams: ['environment_id', 'collection_id', 'document_id', 'file']` and I believe that is the source of the problem, as it indicates that 'file' is a required parameter, contrary to what the API documentation states. The API documentation must be correct, because I can update a metadata-only document just fine from the [Discovery API explorer](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Documents/updateDocument).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make sure you call `updateJsonDocument()` and send an empty object

```
const DiscoveryV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/discovery/v1');
const fs = require('fs');

const discovery = new DiscoveryV1({
  username: 'YOUR USERNAME',
  password: 'YOUR PASSWORD',
  version_date: DiscoveryV1.VERSION_DATE_2017_08_01
});

discovery.updateJsonDocument(
  {
    environment_id: 'YOUR ENVIRONMENT ID',
    collection_id: 'YOUR COLLECTION ID',
    configuration_id: 'YOUR CONFIGURATION ID',
    file: {},
    metadata: { foo: 'bar' }
  },
  function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```

The documentation is not updated but you can see the method [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/discovery/v1.js#L559).

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I was doing it for a while, but the problem with doing it that way is, what was the "metadata" becomes the "document". This makes searches and retrieval complicated because the field names are different, depending on if the input was metadata-only or not (we discard and store just the metadata if the document is over 50MB, Discovery's limit).  If I can do it from the API explorer, shouldn't I be able to do it from the SDK as well?

Comment: So you are saying that even with an empty object you still can upload just the metadata? You can do this with curl but not the SDK?  What's the command you are running?

Comment: That is correct, German. I didn't take the time to get the syntax correct with cURL, but I was able to add metadata-only documents from the watson-api-explorer page (https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/discovery-v1#!/Documents/updateDocument). I simply filled in the environment_id, collection_id, document_id, version, and metadata fields, and did not press the "Choose File" button at all.  I tried it with the generated cURL command afterwards but apparently Swagger doesn't know how to format the metadata either.